# sums and distance of uniform distributions

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two uniformly distributed, independent random variables on the interval $[0,b]$. Let $S = X+Y$ be their sum and $D = |X-Y|$ be their distance.

I have a few questions:

a) To calculate the density of $S$, i can use convolution of the two densities of $X$ and $Y$. (Side-question to the convolution formula: is there a way to avoid case analysis?) Is another possible way to use the following formula?
$P[X+Y \leq t] = \int P[x+Y \leq t] \mu(dx) = \int^1_0 P[Y \leq t-x] \frac{1}{b}$ = ...,
where $\mu$ is the distribution of $X$.

b) The above formula is taken from Billingsley, Thm 20.3 (formula (20.29))
If i use this formula to calculate the cumulative distribution function of $D$, i get $P[|X-Y| \leq t] = \int^b_0 \frac{2t}{b} \mu(dx) = \frac{1}{b^2}\frac{t^2}{2}$, where i used $P[|x-Y| \leq t] = P[Y \in (0,x+t)] - P[Y \in (0,x-t)] = 1_{[0,b]} (x+t) \frac{x+t}{b} - 1_{[0,b]}(x-t) \frac{x-t}{b}$. Integrating this expression from $0$ to $b$ w.r.t. $x$ (and dividing by $b$) i get after some cumbersome calculation, that $P[|X-Y| \leq t] = \frac{1}{b^2} \cdot \frac{t^2}{2}$. For sure, there is again some calc-error, and for sure there are smoother ways to do this..
The densitity then is the derivative, i get $f_D(t) = \frac{t}{b^2}$.

c) Are the random variables $D$ and $S$ independent? Now i know that they are independent if and only if their joint density is the product of the marginal densities, but to check this i would have to calculate the joint density, i guess. Or is there are clear argument why they are independent/dependent? Or what is the usual way to see if two random variables are independent?

d) Is $D = |X-Y|$ a good estimator for the parameter $b$ (length of the interval)?
Let $Z = cD$ for some constant $c$, for which $c$ is $Z$ an unbiased estimator for $b$?
I would say for $c=3$, because $E[D] = \frac{b}{3}$ and therefore $E[Z] = c \frac{b}{3}$
and if i want to have $E[Z]-b = 0$, i have to set $c = 3$. Is that correct?

Now i understand why they are not independent (i like the exlanation more than some thoughless computation), but if somebody could check my calculations above, it would be very much appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: I believe they're not independent, as if you have $S=a<b$, then you definitely know that $X$ and $Y$, as well as $D$ are less than $a$.

Comment: The non-independence may be intuitively clear is we observe that sum very close to $0$ forces the absolute value of the difference to be small.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite follow your derivation of the density of $D$, but note that $0 \leq |X-Y| \leq b,$ so $P(D\leq b)=1,$ not $\frac 1{b^2} \cdot \frac {b^2}2 = \frac 12$ as your result implies.  Moreover, the density is greatest near $0$ and smallest near $b,$ which is the opposite of the effect you would get if the density over $t$ were proportional to $t.$

The density of $S$ between $0$ and $2b$ consists of two linear segments with different slopes, so it's probably more trouble than it's worth (if it is even possible) to avoid any kind of "case analysis."